# Tracking like button referrals from Facebook using the 'fb_ref' parameter in our code

Tags: attributes, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins, referrals

We would like to use the Attribute `fb_ref` - the ref parameter in a like button (in order to track referral clicks and conversions).
Do you have a tutorial or example of how this works on our pages?

Answer (score 3):

When you use the `ref` parameter on a like button, clicks back to your website which were generated by that Like button, contain two extra parameters in the referrer: `fb_ref`, containing the same value you gave to `ref`, and `fb_source` which shows where on Facebook the story was clicked.

This is explained here in the documentation for the like button: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ - search for 'ref'

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see where I can add the fb_ref.
Is it in the like button code?

Comment: As an attribute to the like button code - it's listed in the Attributes section of that document (i.e <fb:like href='whatever' ref='trackingref001'/>)