# logging referrer ID with Facebook page like

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

Is there any way to log the referrer Id for a Facebook page like action.

Use Case:
I have a site with FB like plugin integrated in few modules, which are referencing to a FB page.
I want to log a particular Id (specific to particular module) when user Likes the page, so that I can analyze later which module generated how many likes.

I can find 'ref' option in FB API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button#faqref

But not sure whether it will fit in my scenarios and how.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the ref parameter on a like button, clicks back to your website which were generated by that Like button, contain two extra parameters in the referrer: fb_ref, containing the same value you gave to ref, and fb_source which shows where on Facebook the story was clicked.

BTW, this answer has been previously answered here: [Tracking like button referrals from Facebook using the 'fb_ref' parameter in our code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927759/tracking-like-button-referrals-from-facebook-using-the-fb-ref-parameter-in-our)

Here's some relevant documentation from the Like Button and the Ref Param:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs/#ref

Comment: thanks for your reply. But in my case I have Facebook page, which is getting liked from different places/ modules in my site (through social plugin). I want to findout in Facebook insights, which module in my site generated how many likes. For that, I can assign unique ID per module in my site. I want a way to achieve this.